# Why might a ssd seem to consume dramatically more power than a hdd?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, ssd, battery

System: Acer One laptop (2013) with Intel Pentium 997 1.6 GHz and 4 MB RAM, Windows 10

I replaced a 512 GB Sata hdd with a 120 GB Sata ssd. What I did not expect was the remaining battery time to drop from 3:45 to 2:10, actually I expected more battery time.

I tried to re-calibrate the battery and it seemed to have an impact but that lasted only for one boot.

The ssd boots faster and is quiet. However, the lower battery time would not make up for just that.

A search for this question showed a few threads but all the answers were like this is not possible or buy a new battery.

Comment: Any decent SSD will draw less power. I have a ThinkPad with Samsung SSD and it will go 5 or 6 hours on a full charge. I have a Desktop Lenovo that I replaced the HDD with SSD and it definitely uses less power.

Comment: Because the principle of SSD and HDD is diametrically different. The SSD does not contain any mechanics, but an awful lot of electronics that work at high power (chipset, CPU, communication with memory cells). SSD resembles memory modules or CPU rather than a mechanical disk. There is no complicated electronics on the HDD, as in the case of an SSD. Therefore, the SSD consumes more power and also generates as much heat. In other words, it is due to the manufacturing technology of flash memory chips. It also heats up the USB 3.0 memory storage devices when copying large amounts of data.

Comment: I cannot easily measure the inside of my ThinkPad, but I can open my Desktop case and measure around the drive bays (now SSD). The temperature dropped from about 40 or 50 degrees C to room temperature. So I am seeing something quite different to the above.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt list the make and model of the SSD you purchased, which might help.  However, if I were to hazard a guess, you bought the cheapest, non-name brand, Chinese SSD you could find.  I have seen firsthand how bad some  these drives are.  The electronic are designed so poorly, that the draw  excessive amounts of power, far more than the drive needs.  Then that excessive power is let off as heat.  The excessive power draw is draining your battery and the heat it is putting out is causing your fans to spin more, which also draws power.

Comment: The make and model is WD GREEN WDS120G2GOA, it is cheap but not the cheapest although obviously made in China. It does not get hot at all. My theory is that Windows only "thinks" the battery won't last.

Comment: I think you could be correct if it is cool (and probably therefore) not drawing a lot of current. Try updating both BIOS and Power Driver to see if that corrects battery measurement.